# Pdf generation using phantom.js in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, phantomjs

I am trying to generate pdf using phantom.js in node.js with express.
My js is as follow:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var phantom = require('phantom');

router.get('/pdfDemo', function(req, res, next) {

    var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>My Webpage</title></head>' +
        '<body><h1>My Webpage</h1><p>This is my webpage. I hope you like it' +
        '!</body></html>';

    phantom.create(function (error, ph) {
        ph.createPage(function (error, page) {
            page.set('content', html, function (error) {

                if (error) {
                    console.log('Error setting content: %s', error);
                } else {
                    page.render('page.pdf', function (error) {
                        if (error) console.log('Error rendering PDF: %s', error);
                    });
                }

                ph.exit();
            });
        });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am getting following error while executing this:

```
phantomjs-node: You don't have 'phantomjs' installed

    /paht_to_file/WebStrom WorkSpace/PdfDemo/routes/pdf.js:21
            ph.createPage(function (error, page) {
               ^
    TypeError: Object Error: spawn ENOENT has no method 'createPage'
```

I am using webstrom as development environment. I am new in Node.js and can't able to figure it out what's wrong here. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you install : npm install phantomjs module ?

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen Van Yes i did

Comment: What does `which phantomjs` or `where phantomjs` say when you execute it in a terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with node. You should install `phantomjs` on your computer. You can do so by doing `brew install phantomjs` or `apt-get install phantomjs`, depending on your OS.

Comment: The important fact is that PhantomJS must be properly installed. Some environments have trouble when PhantomJS is installed through npm and node doesn't find the binary file for some reason. In those cases the binary must be installed manually (by putting the binary into a folder that is in the PATH environment variable).